# Ending hex-specified section of a C string literal

Tags: c, string, literals, string-literals

```
char *a = "A\x01B";
```

I typed this and I meant `A` + `\x01` + `B`, but the compiler thought that I meant `A` + `\x1B`. I was thinking it parses two characters after the `\x` as a hexadecimal value, but appears it is not. Then I thought maybe it parses **three** of them and typed:

```
char *a = "A\x001B";
```

But the result was the same, in fact even

```
char *a = "A\x000000000001B";
```

still means `A`+ `0x1b`

So how do I get my next character, which is `B` parsed into a string literal as a character after the `\x1`?

Comment: You could try to split your literals: `"A\x01" "B"`

Comment: Octal escapes (`”\7”`, `”\07”` or `”\007”`) use 1-3 octal digits.  Hex escapes use unbounded sequences of hex digits, as you've found out.

Answer (score 6):

> how do I get my next character, which is B parsed into a string literal as a character after the \x1?

You can do:

```
const char *a = "A\x01" "B";
const char *a = "A\x1""B";
const char *a = "A\001B";
const char *a = "A\01B";
const char *a = "A\1B";
```

With slightly different meaning:

```
const char *a = (const char[]){'A', 1, 'B', 0};
const char a[] = {'A', 1, 'B', 0};
```